# AJAX in wordpress theme loop

Tags: loop, ajax

I'm trying to make a AJAX request on my theme.

I already know wordpress handle AJAX very well, but not directly on theme file. It uses admin-ajax.php for this.

I working on this for a long time and really don't know where to put the code.

I know there need to put information in admin-ajax.php, function.php and have to specify if user is ou not logged in.

Can someone help me with my code?

HTML:

```
<article class="delivery-individual">
        <!-- # CONTENT HERE -->
</article>
```

JQUERY:

```
    <script>
$.ajax({
      url: "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/temakis.php",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(result) {
        $(".delivery-individual").html(result);
      }
    });
</script>
```

EXTERNAL FILE:

```
<h3>Temakis</h3>

<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'temakis');
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<div class="item-individual">
  <img src="<?php the_field("imagem-produto");?>" width="150" height="150" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?> "/>
  <div class="item-individual-info">
  <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
  <p class="descricao-delivery"><? echo get_post_field('post_content'); ?></p>
  <p class="valor-delivery">R$ <? the_field("preco"); ?></p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The request is ok, because i`m getting the h3 correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using the AJAX API ([I have written a number of answers about it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+ajax+api)) and you seem to know that, but you don't seem to be even attempting to use it. Are you asking how to do that?

Comment: Actually i asking how can i make this code works. I cannot makes this code works in any way, could you help me?

Comment: [Please search the site for "AJAX API"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=ajax+api). What you are doing won't work on several levels and the place to start is to use the AJAX API.

Comment: Check out this tutorial for a good starting point http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set user logged in condition on button/ link which triggers ajax request, eg, if user is not logged in open login modal else your function.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your external file **is not loaded under wordpress**, and therefore doesn't have access to any wordpress functions.

As soon as your external file hits `query_posts()` it will throw a fatal error as the function is not defined.

You should use the Ajax API as has been suggested.